# What's the recommended solution/technology to this use case?

Tags: performance, optimization

I'm building a website which offers 1 on 1 coaching on various topics. The coaching is done over the web ( video call, document upload, stuff like this ), and one of the most important things is that the client pays by the minute. My problem is the following: how will I know when a coaching session ends ( so that I can correctly bill the customer )?

I'm planning to store the coaching session in the db roughly like this:

```
  coach_id:integer
  client_id:integer
  created_at:datetime
  updated_at:datetime
  in_progress:boolean
```

At the session's end I will do a difference between updated_at and created_at, and get the length of the session.

Here are the potential problems I see:

- coach loses internet access => in this case, the client will press a button on the website which will notify us that the session had a problem, and the session's `updated_at` will be updated, and `in_progress` will be set to `false`
- client loses internet access => same workflow as if coach loses internet access
- both lose internet access => this is the trickiest case. I am not sure how to notify the server that the session should be considered as finished. I am thinking of doing it via push, and have both the client's browser, and the coach's browser update the server every minute. Worst case scenario, the error would cause a difference of 1 minute to the bill, which is acceptable. The downside is that I think this could load the server a lot, and I don't know if this would still be a viable solution once we will have many users.

What do you think of this approach? In case it matters, the application will be built on Rails 3.2.

Comment: Why dont you look into HTML5 EventSource or WebSockets as possible means of detecting connectivity/loss of connection?

Comment: @PeterAronZentai, yes, but what if both persons lose connectivity? Who will notify the server?

Comment: At least in .NET (and I would guess in all server environments) it is possible to see if the client is still connected (tcp wise). EventSource/WebSockets helps you to establish an always open connection (as opposed to request/response connection with a short period of being connected) that you can monitor if its still operational/open.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai, I've also been thinking that the solution needs to be implemented at the websocket server.

Comment: I don't see any other reliable way...

Comment: I'm creating a demo app, to test how well this will work, and I will update the question once I'm done. In the meantime, perhaps you'd like to add your comments as an answer, so I could upvote them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you look into HTML5 `EventSource` or `WebSockets` as possible means of detecting connectivity/loss of connection?

At least in .NET (and I would guess in all server environments) it is possible to see if the client is still connected (tcp wise). EventSource/WebSockets helps you to establish an always open connection (as opposed to request/response connection with a short period of being connected) that you can monitor if its still operational/open.

So essentialy the solution needs to be implemented at the websocket server.